# Accessing the CarMaker data using Python UDP Socket is not possible?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp, simulation

I’m using python script to collect the data from CarMaker12.0.

I have used this: https://github.com/gmnvh/pycarmaker and it was successful. However this implementation uses TCP protocol.

I want to use UDP protocol in my python script to receive the data from CarMaker.

In the terminal I run `C:\IPG\carmaker\win64-12.0.1\bin\CM.exe -cmdport 12345`, it will open the CarMaker and I run any simple test run.

Here’s the script I run to receive the velocity data from CarMaker using TCP.

**TCP**

```
import socket

tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_addr = (socket.gethostname(),12345)
tcp.connect(server_addr)

msg = “QuantSubscribe {” + ‘Car.v’ + “}\r”
tcp.send(msg.encode())
rsp = tcp.recv(1024)
rsp = rsp.decode().split(“\r\n\r\n”)

read_msg = “expr {$Qu(” + ‘Car.v’ + “)}\r”
tcp.send(read_msg.encode())
str_rx = tcp.recv(300).decode()
rx_list = str_rx.split(“\r\n\r\n”)
print(rx_list)
```

I can able to receive the data from CarMaker from above TCP Implementation.

But when I use the UDP protocol like below,

**UDP**

```
import socket

udp= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_addr = (socket.gethostname(),12345)

msg = “QuantSubscribe {” + ‘Car.v’ + “}\r”
udp.sendto(msg.encode(),server_addr )
rsp = udp.recvfrom(1024)
rsp = rsp.decode().split(“\r\n\r\n”)

read_msg = “expr {$Qu(” + ‘Car.v’ + “)}\r”
udp.sendto(read_msg.encode(),server_addr)
str_rx = udp.recvfrom(300).decode()
rx_list = str_rx.split(“\r\n\r\n”)

print(rx_list)
```

There’s no response at all.

Message Format for TCP and UDP sockets is different?

How to make connections to CarMaker with UDP Socket and CarMaker message/command formats for UDP Protocol.

Comment: The server is a TCP server. You can’t use UDP unless it serves that protocol.

Comment: You meant to say, the server which the CarMaker streams the data is always on TCP socket. Can it be configured to use UDP socket?